# Is it bad Webpack practice to import all libraries that React app needs into one file?

Tags: reactjs, import, webpack

Is it bad Webpack practice to import all the libraries that React application needs in one place, for example inside Libs.js, and then inside every application module get them all with just one import statement ?

Libs.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field, getFormValues, change } from 'redux-form';
import isNull from 'lodash/isNull';


export default {
  React: React,
  PropTypes: PropTypes,
  redux: {
    connect: connect
  },
  form: {
    create: reduxForm,
    change: change,
    getValues: getFormValues,
    Field: Field
  },
  lodash: {
    isNull: isNull
  }
};
```

Any app module

```js
import libs from 'common/libs';
```

Comment: I think if you are using webpack 2/3 - you can do something like this - but you need to check that there is no module duplication when you are building the app for deployment. I would check out webpack-bundle-analyzer to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack and rollup don't need this kind of enclosed module that groups together all libraries. If you are using a bundling system and import react 20 times, the system will not to import and include the code only once, so it's easier to just import what library dependencies you have in the files where they are used.

With this approach you also get more clarity of what libraries are used by which components.

Short answer: Yes, in my opinion, it is a bad practice and I wouldn't do it in any project.

Comment: Yes I understand, but let me tell you this ... that Libs.js file would hold only libraries from node_modules folder and only those that are imported literally in every app's React component. There is like 20-30 classes in the project and every file imports the same stuff over and over again. Sometimes it's even 20-25 lines of imports. Using Libs.js I could get them all with one line. Maybe I wouldn't see exactly what libraries component uses but the top section of the file would be much clearer and node imports would be separated from app imports.

Comment: Based on personal experience, it's not 25 lines. Also, if you truly want to build an app that respects the module patterns everyone else is familiar with from vanilla js you should import or require all modules in each file. 

The thing you are trying to create is a convention in your app. You are the master of that convention. If your team is comfortable with it, or you work alone, then go for it.